# Primary Contact Role into custom Lookup Field on Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, lookup

I need to bring the primary contact role in the opp page. I created a flow https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000e4QeQAI from this link but the process builder is not working.
I have the primary contact role but the contact name (lookup field from the opp page) is blank (it does not bring the primary contact name)
What I am doing wrong?
Opp Contact_Name ID Is null Booledan True
(all of the conditions are met)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Process that runs a Flow requires a triggerable event to start running. The `OpportunityContactRole` object doesn't support triggers, so changes to Contact Roles are not capable of starting any automations - whether that is triggers, processes, workflow rules, or anything else.

Your Process and Flow will only run when some change is made to the Opportunity itself. That's why you see SteveMo in the thread you linked recommending *inverting* the flow of data entry here - populating a field on the Opportunity, which is triggerable, and using a Flow to create the Primary Opportunity Contact Role from that event.

There is not much in the way of good workarounds for this need. You can run a scheduled Apex job on a regular basis to synchronize the primary Opportunity Contact Role with the Opportunity, or you can create a custom UI for managing contact roles, or you can invert the data entry flow to place the user action on a triggerable object (Opportunity).

Until that object becomes triggerable, there won't be a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks David. I just copy exactly the Flow and the process builder and it does not work for me (it looks like it work for other people). I just change the stage in the opp page in order to trigger the flow but the Primary Contact lookup field is not updated. Can you please send a print screen with your suggestion? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't have this solution implemented in any of my orgs, @DianaMoize, so I'm afraid I can't share a screenshot.